# Compile C with gcc and the -m32 flag on macOS Catalina

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I am attempting to compile a tiny C program on a Mac. I am using Homebrew's `gcc-10`. I want to compile in 32 bit mode with the `-m32` flag.

Running `gcc-10 file.c` compiles with no problems.

However, running `gcc-10 -m32 file.c` gives the error:

```
.../ccwWxcnm.s:5:2: error: instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode
        pushl   %ebp
        ^
```

I am aware that macOS removed support for 32 bit programs, so I expected to have to do something to make this work but I cannot find an instance of my issue, nor a solution, after significant research time.

How can I use the `-m32` flag with `gcc` on macOS Catalina?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the package libc6-dev-i386 to test the -m32 gcc option on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: I have not seen a way to use lib6-dev-i386 on a Mac. Do you know of a way to do it?